# According to Preterists what happens next?

Tags: heaven, prophecy, preterism

Is there an end of the world? Or does it pretty much continue on like this forever, ever populating heaven (and "hell"?)?

Answer (score 1):

Preterism in itself is just as divided as most eschatological doctrines are. You get two main groups: partial preterists and full preterists, and in these groups, there are smaller groupings with different eschatological timelines.

There is definitely value in the Preterist eschatology, there are some things we cannot get away from. John says in Revelation 1 vs 1:

> "The Revelation of Jesus Christ, which God gave Him to show His servants—things which must shortly take place."

According to that introduction, I cannot see how one could interpret it as anything else other than "things which must shortly take place". There is definitely a historical significance about the time the book was written and the context it is introduced in, to gloss over that would be blindness.

There is also another clue in that verse, it is a "Revelation", an "unveiling" of Jesus Christ. Again in verse 3 He says:

> "For the time is near."

Again in Revelation 22 vs 6 Jesus says:

> "6 Then he said to me, “These words are faithful and true.” And the Lord God of the holy prophets sent His angel to show His servants the things which must shortly take place.

And what is about to take place? See vs 7

> 7 “Behold, I am coming quickly! Blessed is he who keeps the words of the prophecy of this book.”

And again in vs 20

> 20 He who testifies to these things says, “Surely I am coming quickly.”

Something was about to take place, shortly after John received this revelation. If Jesus said He was coming quickly and these things were to take place shortly, often repeating it, then why do we go and interpret it otherwise? Is it because we cannot open the seals, so we try to fit something in that will suit our understanding? I'm talking about the whole "thousand years as a day" justification...

No, where Genesis is the book of seeds, where the plans and purposes of God are established; Revelation is a consummation of those things. Where Adam and Eve were expelled from the Garden, now the New Jerusalem descends from Heaven.

Everything in the Bible has worked to this one point, and it finds it's fulfillment in Jesus Christ. Revelation is the introduction of something new, that was shortly to take place.

The whole theme of the book of Revelation is about Christ being revealed in His body. It is something that started shortly after John's vision and it is something that is still continuing today.

Once you can see Christ revealed through this book, then Revelation goes from being a scary book about doom and gloom to the most wonderful love story you will ever know.

Different eschatologies end up very similar, Preterism, and all shades of Preterism, or not. It ends with Christ having preeminence over all things. What is important though more than that, is how we get there and what our role is in this. That is where the rub is, and that is the question you should be asking.

> Proverbs 25 vs 2 It is the glory of God to conceal a matter,
>   But the glory of kings is to search out a matter.